# For every integer in an array, find the nearest greater integer both before and after it

Tags: java, time-limit-exceeded, complexity

The given code gives correct output but exceeds the time limit and I have no idea how to optimize it. I know it is of \$O(n^2)\$ complexity but I am not able to get anywhere near to optimizing it. Even a few hints would be appreciated.

The question is this:

> The problem is given an array \$A\$ having \$N\$ integers, for each \$i\$ \$(1\le i\le N)\$, find \$x+y\$, where \$x\$ is the largest number less than \$i\$ such that \$A[x]\gt A[i]\$ and \$y\$ is the smallest number greater than \$i\$ such that \$A[y]\gt A[i]\$. If there is no \$x\lt i\$ such that \$A[x]\gt A[i]\$, then take \$x=-1\$. Similarly, if there is no \$y\gt i\$ such that \$A[y]\gt A[i]\$, then take \$y=-1\$.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Alpha{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    int n=0,i=0,x=-1,y=-1,sum=0,m1,m2;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    n=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    Stack<Integer> stk=new Stack<>();
    long arr[] = new long[n];
    String str[]=br.readLine().split(" ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=Long.parseLong(str[i]);
    }
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        x=-1;
        y=-1;
        for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(arr[j]>arr[i])
            {
                x=j+1;
                break;
            }
        }
        stk.push(x);
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]>arr[i])
            {
                y=j+1;
                break;
            }
        }
        stk.push(y);

    }
    while(!stk.isEmpty())
    {
        m1=stk.peek();
        stk.pop();
        m2=stk.peek();
        stk.pop();
        sum=m1+m2;
        System.out.print(sum+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it exceed the time limit for any input, or for what inputs does it complete successfully?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Links can rot. [Please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the following explanations, I'm going to use 1-based indexes just like the description does, even though it's confusing seeing as Java arrays have zero-based indexes.

  Obviously, \$x_1=-1\$. Also, if \$a_{i-1}\gt a_i\$, then \$x_i=i-1\$. So as long as every integer is less than the last one, we can just store the \$x\$ for every array element one by one.

  But what if we encounter an \$a_i\$ where \$a_{i-1}\le a_i\$? Do we need to iterate over all the preceding elements to find the nearest greater integer? No, because we already know the position of the next greater integer before \$a_{i-1}\$, namely \$x_{i-1}\$. Every element between \$a_{i-1}\$ and \$a_{x_{i-1}}\$ will be less than or equal to \$a_{i-1}\$, and therefore also less than or equal to \$a_i\$ (since \$a_{i-1}\le a_i\$), so we can skip all these elements and jump to \$a_{x_{i-1}}\$.

  If \$a_{x_{i-1}}\gt a_i\$, we have found \$x_i=x_{i-1}\$. Otherwise, we repeat the process, i.e. jumping to the next greater integer before \$a_{x_{i-1}}\$ by querying \$x_{x_{i-1}}\$, and so on, until we arrive at an integer that is greater than \$a_i\$ (or until there are no more array elements).

  The same process can be repeated in the other direction of the array to find all \$y\$ values. So instead of calculating \$x\$ and \$y\$ for every array element independently, you can use the already calculated values to speed up the process, based on the relationships explained above.
- Apart from that, your code is a bit chaotic. I would suggest separating user interface from program logic, for example writing one method that accepts an `int[]` (or `long[]`) as a parameter and returns an `int[]` of equal length containing the sum of \$x\$ and \$y\$ for every array element, and another method that reads user input from the command line (or from wherever), converts this input to an `int[]` or `long[]`, passes this array to the other method, and converts the `int[]` returned by the method to the required output format.

  Note that \$x+y\$ may overflow an `int`, but a Java array can only contain a maximum of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (\$=2^{31}-1\$) elements (and that's only in theory, I think I've read that, in practice, even with memory implications aside, the maximum length of an array might be slightly lower), so the maximum sum that could ever occur is `Integer.MAX_VALUE + Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2` for an element at the *one-based* index `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1`, and `Integer.MAX_VALUE + Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2` \$=2^{32}-4\$ still fits into 32 bits, so no information is lost if you store the value in an `int`, it's just that Java treats the highest-order bit of an `int` as a sign-bit because Java doesn't support unsigned 32-bit integers.

  Also, \$2^{32}-4\$ overflows to `-4`, and the smallest possible non-overflowing result of \$x+y\$ is \$-2\$, so it will always be possible to tell an overflow and a truly negative result apart. An `int[]` would therefore suffice to store the necessary results.
- The class `Stack` is antiquated – the documentation recommends to use `Deque` implementations instead.
- Reduce the scope of variables to the smallest extent necessary to make the code less confusing. `x` and `y` are only needed in the second `for` loop (the outer `for` loop), and they also don't need to keep their state from one iteration to the next, so they should not only be initialized, but also declared there. Likewise, `sum`, `m1` and `m2` can be declared in the last `while` loop.

  Also, declaring one `int` variable `i` outside the `for` loops and using this variable in both loops gives the illusion that the value of `i` in the second `for` loop somehow depends on its final value after the first loop. This is not true, as you manually set it to `n-1`, so it would be less confusing if you either declared a separate `i` in every loop so that these `i`s don't exist outside the loop for which they are relevant, or you don't explicitly set `i` to `n-1` at the beginning of the second loop. I would prefer the first version because it keeps the loop variables in their loop, even if it takes a few microseconds longer because the new `i` has to be initialized to `n-1`.
- Instead of storing an entire input String in memory, you could wrap a `Scanner` around an `InputStream` to parse it into a `long[]`:

  ```java
  Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  int n = inputScanner.nextInt();
  inputScanner.nextLine();

  long[] arr = new long[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      arr[i] = inputScanner.nextLong();
  }
  ```

  This is not equivalent to your code, because it doesn't require the array elements to be on one line. I doubt that this matters, but theoretically, you could configure the scanner to exlude line terminators from its delimiter pattern after you read the value of `n` and skip the rest of the line by invoking `Scanner.useDelimiter(String)` and passing a custom regular expression that matches whitespace excluding line terminators (the default delimiter pattern of a `Scanner` is whitespace).